# Can I make this style in pure CSS (button)

Tags: css

How can I get this gradient effect in css?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following css and html to achieve something the button in your post

**css**

```
#button {
    background-color: #7BCEE6;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7BCEE6, #3F7DBB); /* FF3.6 */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #7BCEE6), color-stop(1, #3F7DBB)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #7BCEE6, #3F7DBB);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#7BCEE6', EndColorStr='#3F7DBB'); /* IE6–IE9 */
    width:120px;
    height:40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px; /* FF1+ */
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4 */
    border-radius: 12px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome */
}
#image {
    width:25px;
    height:40px;
    background:#930;
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
}
#text {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #888; /* FF3.5+, Opera 9+, Saf1+, Chrome */
    color:#fff;
    font-size:22px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="button">
  <div id="image"></div>
  <div id="text">Reports</div>
</div>
```

live example: http://jsbin.com/ebuno5

**Notes**
Where is the red block, is supposed you can add a png image. Also you have to keep in mind that most css3 under internet explorer 8 is not supported. To add some css3 functionality for ie you can you the [pie.htc](http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I saw these examples recently:

http://lab.simurai.com/css/buttons/

These use a lot of bleeding edge CSS so test thoroughly...

Answer (score 1):

Check out: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient/

Answer (score 1):

You need CSS3 for that. It isn't supported in all browsers though. Check http://css3generator.com/ to generate your gradient. It sends you to an awesome gradient editor: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/. Here an example to create a gradient with some support for older browsers:

```
/* old browsers */
background: #1E5799; 
/* firefox */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1E5799 0%, #2989D8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%);
/* webkit */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1E5799), color-stop(50%,#2989D8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8));
/* ie */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1E5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 );
```

You can also use CSS3 PIE to add CSS3 support for Internet Explorer: http://css3pie.com/. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes definately, I used http://gradients.glrzad.com/ in order to generate this CSS:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.45, rgb(26,106,163)),
    color-stop(0.87, rgb(36,183,224))
);

background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(26,106,163) 45%,
    rgb(36,183,224) 87%
);
```

However be aware (as I am sure you are) that this will not work in Internet Explorer.

Also you must check out **Chris Coyier's CSS3 [button maker](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/)**.

Comment: IE has gradients too, mate: `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#24B7E0', endColorstr='#1A6AA3',GradientType=0 );`

Answer (score 0):

I use [this site](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for gradients.

Note however that Opera (currently at ver. 11) does not support CSS3 gradients at all, so make sure it looks OK with some sort of fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CSS Pie](http://css3pie.com/). It provides cross-browser border-radius, box-shadow and gradient functionality